# Locking Performance & Alternatives

Tags: c#, multithreading, performance, locking, publish-subscribe

I have a class which pushes data out to subscribed listeners very frequently, from multiple threads. To make the class thread-safe I have locked on a dedicated object instance as you can see. The problem is that locking while iterating the list reduces throughput of the class by nearly 30% with a simple subscriber that calculates the throughput of published values.

Is there an alternative way of making this process thread-safe that might have less of an overhead? Any ideas would be appreciated.

```
public abstract class Publisher<T> : IPublisher<T>
{
    protected readonly object InstanceLock = new object();
    protected readonly List<ISubscriber<T>> Subscribers = new List<ISubscriber<T>>();

    public virtual void Subscribe(ISubscriber<T> subscriber)
    {
        lock (InstanceLock)
        {
            if (!Subscribers.Contains(subscriber))
            {
                Subscribers.Add(subscriber);
            }
        }
    }
    public virtual void Unsubscribe(ISubscriber<T> subscriber)
    {
        lock (InstanceLock)
        {
            if (Subscribers.Contains(subscriber))
            {
                Subscribers.Remove(subscriber);
            }
        }
    }
    public virtual bool IsSubscribed(ISubscriber<T> subscriber)
    {
        lock (InstanceLock)
        {
            return Subscribers.Contains(subscriber);
        }
    }
    public virtual void Publish(T value)
    {
        lock (InstanceLock)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Subscribers.Count; i++) Subscribers[i].Record(value);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the subscriber I am using to measure throughput

```
public sealed class CountRateSubscriber : StatSubscriber<double>
{
    private DateTime _firstUpdated;
    private DateTime _lastUpdated;
    private int _count;

    public override void Record(double value)
    {
        lock (InstanceLock)
        {
            _count++;
            _lastUpdated = DateTime.UtcNow;

            if (_count == 1)
            {
                _firstUpdated = _lastUpdated;
            }
            else
            {
                _value = _count / (_lastUpdated - _firstUpdated).TotalSeconds;
            }

        }
    }
}

public abstract class StatSubscriber<T> : ValueSubscriber<double, T>
{
}

public abstract class ValueSubscriber<TIn, TOut> : ISubscriber<TIn>
{
    protected readonly object InstanceLock = new object();

    protected TOut _value;

    public TOut Value
    {
        get
        {
            lock (InstanceLock)
            {
                return _value;
            }
        }
    }

    public abstract void Record(TIn value);
}
```

EDIT:  So I've tried all of the folling and theyre all slower than just using `lock`:

- Copying `Subscribers` to a local variable and not locking
- `ReaderWriterLockSlim`
- `ConcurrentDictionary`
  -

Comment: Maybe you can use a fixed length array as the subscribers buffer and then use an Interlocked approach, in this way you will never lock the buffer.

Comment: @Gusman It could be a good idea, and maybe there should be some lock when the size of the array should be increased (i.e. using interlocked to exchange the smaller array to other with more free slots...)

Comment: well, I said "fixed length array", not "variable length array", if you need to grow the buffer size then there will be locking for sure.

Comment: Assume something can be done. But the real question is though "are your **subscribers** thread-safe"? i.e. is it safe to call `Record` concurrently.

Comment: @IvanStoev Yes they are, I've added the code for the subscriber that's measuring throughput for my tests.

Comment: Ok. But that introduces another problem. Imagine we eliminate the subscriber list locks.  The result will be that instead of the collection lock, the producing threads will just start waiting on the each subscriber lock (since they are iterated in one and the same order). Looks like what you really need is a different design - for instance multiple producers/single dedicated consumer etc. It might be worth taking a look at Reactive Extensions or TPL DataFlow.

Comment: why is the subscriber locking?

Comment: @KrisVandermotten That's a good point, I suppose it would allow a subscriber to subscribe to multiple publishers at once on different threads, but that isn't the intended use. I will rethink that. Thanks.

Comment: The real question is: are subscribers listening to multiple publishers, or is there one subscriber instance per publisher? In the latter case, you don't have to lock in the subscriber, as there is no concurrent access there.

Answer (score 1):

If the Publish method is your bottleneck, you can get the lock out of Publish at the cost of some additional overhead in Subscribe.  Basically we copy the list when subscribing, then replace the list with the copy.  There are race issues if you care about the ordering of Subscribe/Unsubscribe/Publish (you might get a Record call after you've called Unsubscribe if the list change wasn't yet observed by Publish), but that might be okay.

```
public abstract class Publisher<T> : IPublisher<T>
{
    protected readonly object InstanceLock = new object();
    protected List<ISubscriber<T>> Subscribers = new List<ISubscriber<T>>();

    public virtual void Subscribe(ISubscriber<T> subscriber)
    {
        lock (InstanceLock)
        {
            var newSubscribers = Subscribers.ToList();
            if (!newSubscribers.Contains(subscriber))
            {
                newSubscribers.Add(subscriber);
                Subscribers = newSubscribers;
            }
        }
    }
    public virtual void Unsubscribe(ISubscriber<T> subscriber)
    {
        lock (InstanceLock)
        {
            var newSubscribers = Subscribers.ToList();
            if (newSubscribers.Contains(subscriber))
            {
                newSubscribers.Remove(subscriber);
                Subscribers = newSubscribers;
            }
        }
    }
    public virtual bool IsSubscribed(ISubscriber<T> subscriber)
    {
        lock (InstanceLock)
        {
            return Subscribers.Contains(subscriber);
        }
    }
    public virtual void Publish(T value)
    {
        var subscribers = Subscribers;
        for (int i = 0; i < subscribers.Count; i++) subscribers[i].Record(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Dan, Thanks for your comments. Unfortunately I have already tried just copying the Subscribers list to a local variable before iterating, and that alone is slower than the lock method. Im starting to think I can't do much about it.

Comment: @Ashigore, I'm very surprised that copying to a local variable would be slower.  Note that we're not copying the list itself here, just the reference.

Comment: Ah yes of course, sorry, I tested creating a copy of the list. I will give this a shot. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hard to tell what's possible w/o more scope. So I have to guess.
When do subscribers use the data? is it when it's pushed to them or do they have their own processing loop somewhere?

Having writers go all the way to every single reader is a source of much evil and you cannot expect it to scale well with number of readers. And having readers write anything at all (even if it's "only" a lock) makes them sort of writers.
Instead to W writes and R reads, you have W+R and R reads.... lots of cache lines ping pong....

If I'm guessing correctly, and readers have their own processing threads, you can *share* the data from the publishers rather than pushing it to each and every one of them.

You can use a seqlock - a writer would lock by spinning till the seq is even, then atomically add 1 to the seq (maybe fail here - restart the process), update the data, and finally unlock by adding another 1 to the sequence, making it even again.
A reader thread would spin till the seq is even, copy the data, check the seq is the same even number. If not, spin again....

This would get the readers the last value in the fastest way possible as they have nothing to lock. They are completely read-only. Old values are lost.
The writers will also get the fastest path possible. They have to compete with each other, no way around that, but at least they don't have to compete with readers.

Answer (score -1):

The idea is not to distribute the data when you publish it.

Make it a multi step process.

Publish -> put data on a CENTRAL list. A distribution thread reads from this list and then sends the data to all subscribers.

As you get more subscribers, that may bottleneck. If that is the case, add another step. publish -> main list -> sublists (one for example for 1000 subscribers) -> final distribution

This way you can avoid excessive locking and more important you can keep the data source fast.

Now, the subscriber list. Forget the List. Use an array of arrays. Incidentally the subarrays would be the subthreads above ;) The trick is - you LOCK for adding and removal, but you do not lock for distribution. When a subscriber is added or removed you allocate a NEW array and copy the information into it. Then you RPLACE the array used for distribution. Lock around that makes sure memory barrier is handled properly.

The result is that there is never a change on a subscriber array - as the new list replaces the old.

This - obviously - only works if the GC and array allocation are not significant time consumers. Which normally is the case.

I use that for a highly scalable trading application. Market and trading updates are distributed by this and I never ever have to lock for the data distribution to wait because of add/delete.

Comment: IMO this means more readers and writers to get in the action so will slow down the publishing further. The problem is not the changing of subscriber list but having multiple writers and multiple readers on different threads.

Comment: Actually no. First, it makes sure that the publisher is finished fast, regardless how many subscribers are there. This is critical. Second, it allows a modern not single core processor to use multiple threads to distribute the data - anything else is stupid. Third, it avoids having a real lock on publication at all. I use a spinlock to synchronize multiple writers, but I void a full lock except when the distribution list changes. There is a cost there - but in my world (and that of most people doing data distribution) that is a RARE event (compared to data distribution).

Comment: The trick always is: (a) keep locks as short as possible and (b) do require as few locks as possible. My solution achieves both. Yes, you can downvote it - but unless you can come up with a better scheme, that does not speak of your intelligence. I have a goal to have 1000+ active subscribers in machine with sub millisecond delays on a decent machine (that is 16 cores today) and I have no intention to not use those cores. Data wise I can handle tens of thousands - but my consumers at the moment live on the same machine, so CPU usage goes a little up.

Comment: I think this is interesting, what you've said, I will look into testing an implementation like this an see what happens, thank you.

Comment: @TomTom, I absolutely agree you have to use all cores. The cores you add to the writers you take away from the readers. Who's to say which are more important?

Comment: A profiler. You do know how to use one, or? That is critical. I can tell you taht on my current test environment the latest iteration using 100 data targets (all trading strategies) shows up at the end of the list. Despire using around 210 names pipes. Reading and writing speeds in data distribution are total non issues. Also, during reading/writeing I am not locking anything - thanks to the interlocked class.

Comment: This obviously depends on what these strategies are doing. Since you can run 100 of them, I guess nothing is pinned to dedicated cores, and you said yourself, you try to achieve delays of <1ms. I target things that work <1us and then the traders ask "how many nanos?".... I'd think that in your env the starts are the important thing and not the param changes that are late 1ms anyway, so who cares for that lock?

Comment: Well, if you ask "how many nanos" then I have bad news for you: Incompetent system design on your end. Windows is NOT ABLE TO DO EXTREME ACCURACY. A tuned linux kernel will run circles around you. This is why all HFT traders do not use windows. And your question is badly formulated - it does not even mention those hard requirements. Which, btw., invalidate ANY type of multi threading in windows (with a 15ms scheduler interval). I am targeting 1ms switch times for up to 1000 strategies on a server.